# How do I use variables inside a arcpy toolbox function?

Tags: python, arcpy, arctoolbox, python-toolbox

I have a point file and I need to make a lot of buffers in specific increments but I can't figure out how to interate through a list inside the buffer function. Here is what I have:

```
import arcpy  
city_pts = "C:\Urban_Land_Project\Cities\WI_cities.shp"
buffer_sizes = [1,2,4,7,10,15,20,30]
for x in buffer_sizes:
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(city_pts, "C:\Urban_Land_Project\City_buffers\WI_city_buffers*km.shp","2 Kilometers" ,"FULL","ROUND","NONE"," #")
```

I need to have each buffered file to be named "WI_city_buffers*km.shp" with the * being the buffer size. How do I get the arcpy.Buffer_analysis to iterate through my list and apply each buffer distance and proper name?

Comment: Cross posted on [Esri forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/95163-Problems-iterating-through-a-list-inside-a-toolbox-function-using-python.)

Comment: The problem and solution here is a general Python one, so I am voting to close this as general software development, better suited for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 3):

One of the easiest way to accomplish this would be to use [str.format()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
import arcpy  
city_pts = r"C:\Urban_Land_Project\Cities\WI_cities.shp"
buffer_sizes = [1,2,4,7,10,15,20,30]
for x in buffer_sizes:
    city_buff = r"C:\Urban_Land_Project\City_buffers\WI_city_buffers{0}km.shp".format(x)
    buff_dist = "{0} Kilometers".format(x)
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(city_pts, city_buff, buff_dist, "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "#")
```

Another way would be to use concatenation, but I find it harder to read:

```
import arcpy  
city_pts = r"C:\Urban_Land_Project\Cities\WI_cities.shp"
buffer_sizes = [1,2,4,7,10,15,20,30]
for x in buffer_sizes:
    city_buff = r"C:\Urban_Land_Project\City_buffers\WI_city_buffers" + str(x) + "km.shp"
    buff_dist = str(x) + " Kilometers"
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(city_pts, city_buff, buff_dist, "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "#")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is going to help out with a lot of work down the road!