# Adding mxd path to CSV by Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, csv, hebrew

I'm trying to write a python script that adds to a csv file the date, time and mxd path.

I tried to run the script from the Python IDLE without the mxd path and I succeeded to add the date and the time but when I trying to run the script from a tool box in ArcMap it does not work.

Below is my code so far:

```py
import csv
import os
import time
import arcpy
date=time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
time1=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
path=str(mxd.filePath)
with open('log.csv', 'a') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    data = [[date, time1,path]]
    a.writerows(data)
```

It work now but i still have two problems:

1. My mxd path have Hebrew letter so i received - "'ascii' codec can't encode characters" i tried to use .encode('utf-8') but it didn't work.
2. In the csv file i getting a row blank between row to row, How can i fix it?

Comment: Might not solve your issue, but you should use the [binary flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) when reading/writing files with the `csv` module.

Comment: Check out this answer to one of my [questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148327/how-do-you-use-windows-folders-as-acrpy-parameters). ArcGIS can have some odd behaviours when it comes to manipulating file paths.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me when I add it to a Script Tool and then run it.

Make sure that you have actually saved the MXD. Just opening ArcMap then running your script will not return a file path as the document has not been saved!