# Debugging ArcPy error 000258?

Tags: arcpy, cad, error-000258

I have written a script that searches through microstation CADD files, finds ones that conform to a certain naming convention, and pulls them into a geodatabase using the CADtoGeodatabase tool. This script works fine for about an hour and then stops working. No error messages show up in the console. A window just pops up saying that python has stopped working.

I know that there is about 3000 files that need to be converted and my script crashes after about 220. Before trying the conversion I ensure that the file path has no spaces and I have removed all print statements from the script. Adding these two steps allowed the script to run a little longer (originally crashes after about 200 files).

What might be causing this to happen?

```
import os, logging, re, arcpy

LOG_FILENAME = 'CADcopy.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME, level=logging.DEBUG)
rootDir = "CADDirectory"


exten = 'namingConventionMatchRegex'
arcpy.env.workspace = "workspace"
counter = 0
def step(ext, dirname, names):
    #print dirname

    x = re.search("xample",dirname.lower())
    if(x):
        return #Do not try to process example data
    for name in names:

        r = re.search(ext, name.lower())
        if(r):
           global counter
           counter = counter + 1
           fileName = os.path.join(dirname, name)
           s = re.search(" ",fileName)
           if(s):
               #print("{} skipped because file path contains space character.".format(name))
               logging.debug("Unable to convert ,{},. File location: ,{}".format(name, os.path.join(dirname, name)))
               return

           #This block gets basic information about the file from its directory tree and incorporates it into the new dataset name
           if name.lower().endswith("endingType1"):
               planType = "Type1"
           else:
               planType = "Type2"

           split = fileName.split('CommonDirectory')
           split2 = split[1].split('\\')
           table = split2[1]+split2[2]+'_'+str(counter)+planType

           #Try to convert to geodatabase. If it already exists, do nothing, else log the filename and path for later review
           try:
               arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion(fileName, arcpy.env.workspace, table, 100)
           except:
               msg = arcpy.GetMessages(2)
               if(msg.startswith("ERROR 000258")):
                  pass 
                  #print("File already exists")
               else:
                  #print("Failed to convert {} at filePath {}".format(table, fileName))
                  logging.debug("Failed to convert ,{}, at filePath ,{}".format(table, fileName))

os.path.walk(rootDir, step, exten)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the script that you are using.

Comment: Added. I just had to clean it up a little.

Comment: Are you getting anything in your log from failed conversions?  If you are post a few lines from the the log as well.

Comment: Are you maybe running out of memory? Can you try separating parts of your function (use os.walk to compile a list of files, then iterate over the list and import to GDB). os.path.walk is deprecated anyway.

Comment: When I first wrote the program I was getting a lot of errors in the log, and in every case it seemed the error was caused by spaces in the filename. That is why I added the line before the Try so it never attempts to convert those files. I simply log when I encounter this. In the 220 files that were converted, there were no errors in the most recent run. I will try your suggestion of separating functionality.

Comment: Do you know what I should be using besides os.path.walk?

Comment: @SebastianYoung [`arcpy.da.walk()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm) could be an option

Comment: @SebastianYoung Does it always stop on the same file?  What is the file name for that file, and the filesize?  What happens if you remove that file from the process?

Comment: @SebastianYoung Can you remove your `try`/`except` and see if any other error messages are produced (that may be being masked by the try/except)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem in the past, I'm not sure if you're having the same issue but here is the answer that helped me out:

[How do you use Windows Folders as arcpy parameters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148327/how-do-you-use-windows-folders-as-acrpy-parameters)

A lot of the arcpy functions are just wrappers around a COM library, so weird things can happen because file paths are treated like escaped strings even when you use \\ in the path.